# Hadoop switching to new HDFS "image"

Tags: exception, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I have new HDFS local storage directories (`dfs.namenode.name.dir` and `dfs.datanode.data.dir`), the actual local directories under which HDFS stores data (both for **namenode**, **secondarynamenode** and **datanode**), with all the necessary things (edits, fsimage, etc.). I would like to switch from my current HDFS to this new HDFS.

I order to to do this I have stopped the cluster (I run in pseudo-distributed mode), I have edited the **hdfs-site.xml** config (modified the paths) and started the cluster.

However the **NameNode** fails to start based on the following error:

```
FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Exception in namenode join
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.IncorrectVersionException: Unexpected version of storage directory /path/to/NameNodeDir. Reported: -X. Expecting = -Y.
```

Why this doesn't work? As I said I have a whole "image/snapshot" of a properly working new HDFS (the whole thing: name, secondary, data). I thought that I could simply "swap" the HDFS config for the new one and it should work.

**I can not format the NameNode**, as the new HDFS "image" contains data. What I am trying to achieve is to "plugin" new HDFS, replacing the old one, without any modifications to the new HDFS "data/meta" files.

One of the potential problem might be the YARN/HDFS version missmatch. As stated here (http://hortonworks.com/blog/hdfs-metadata-directories-explained), the key **layoutVersion** in `VERSION` file in `namenode/current` is the different `X` from `Y`. The same key on my previous HDFS "instance" had a `Y` corresponding to the one visible in the logs. To simplify new HDFS **layoutVersion** value is `X`, old HDFS **layoutVersion** value is `Y`. I will try to upgrade to YARN 2.6 in order to verify this.

For any help I would be grateful.

regards

**SOLUTION**

The problem was with HDFS version mismatch, as I have written in the comment to user  Mikhail Golubtsov. I was trying to run newer HDFS metadata with the use of binaries from older HDFS version, thus the error. If anybody encounters similar problem, just update/upgrade you YARN/HDFS version to the appropriate one. This has solved the issue for me.

Comment: As far as I get it you're trying to run newer namenode version against the older version metadata? If so there must be some update scripts for that. For example Cloudera demands some update mechanisms to be applied for performing CDH update.

Comment: The other way around I believe. Old hdfs binaries (version, in fact whole YARN) run with the newer version HDFS metadata. If my guess with the problem is correct. X is higher than Y.

Comment: Any updates on this , i am facing the similar issue